# Running chromium with --app and --class results in chromium using the favicon instead of specified icon

Tags: gnome, chrome, .desktop

I've made the following desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=appname
Exec=chromium --user-data-dir=profiledir --app=someurl --class appname
Icon=pathtoappicon
StartupWMClass=appname
```

I'm using gnome, and my "app" appears in the application menu with the correct icon as expected, however, the window icon and the icon that appears in the dash is the website's favicon instead. This only happens on chromium, when I make the same exact desktop entry but use firefox instead I get the correct icon everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Under X11, the icon specified in a desktop file has no direct influence in the icon an application sets as window icon. It defines what a menu entry launching the program looks like.

So, the behaviour you're observing seems to be right – the icon that firefox uses as window icon and that is used to mark the firefox entry in start menus just happen to be the same, or scaled versions of each other.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. What I meant by window icon is the icon that's present on a window when you open the gnome activities overview with the super key. Also the dash icons. At any rate, with firefox the correct custom icon is used in both of those places.